# How to return a value from a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

This is my function.

```
    displayTripsViews(datas) {
      datas.tripLineItemDetails.map((data)=> (data))
  }
```

I want to return data from the above function. can anyone help me with this?

[image]

Comment: Your `.map` is not doing anything at the moment, btw.

Answer (score 0):

simply you just need to return the map function.

```
 displayTripsViews(datas) {
      return datas.tripLineItemDetails.map((data)=> (data))
  }
```

Comment: its not working bro its returning datas which I had passed in argument. I need data to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

When you have one line you can even do this, that will return your value.

```
 displayTripsViews = (datas) => datas.tripLineItemDetails.map((data) => (data.tripDate))
```

Comment: Its not returning data bro its returning datas which I had passed as argument.

Comment: Explain what you want exactly. If you have for example an object datas : { tripLineItemDetails: ["12-04-2021", "15-04-2021"]}, your function will return a new array that will be ["12-04-2021", "15-04-2021"]

Comment: See the screen shot in data I am getting the above json response format. After I used above function and printing data in console I am getting individual objects I need that data value to use in my code.

Comment: displayTripsViews = (datas) => datas.tripLineItemDetails.map((data) => (console.log('abc',data))

Comment: in console on typing abc I am getting individual objects how can I return that response.

Comment: I cannot see you print, just write your JSON here.

Comment: I had updated question and posted image over there please check

Comment: Already updated my answer, check it. This way you get and array of dates. You need to explain what you mean by "data" dude.........

Comment: Need objects in the tripLineItemDetails array. in argument I am passing tripDateLineItems array which is main array.